# Convexity and Closedness of the set of all ND matrices

Tags: general-topology

I have a problem that states:
Let ND be the set of all negative definite matrices. Decide if ND is closed, open, or convex.

Can anyone offer ideas that would point me in the right direction?

Comment: First of all, consider each property separately. Write out the definition explicitly for this particular set; in particular, what is the topology on this set?

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of exercices, you should start with small examples if you really have no idea wether it is true or not.

For example, considering the $1\times 1$ matrices $\begin{pmatrix}-\cfrac{1}{n}\end{pmatrix}$ could help you for one of the properties.

For another property, you probably should look at matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}-1&a\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\b&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and see what you get when you, for example, sum them.

And then, after looking at the $2\times2$ case, the third property appears to be true so you look at your notes to see how you could prove it. And you see a theorem that makes you think that if you had a continuous function that took a matrix and gave back its eigenvalues, that'd be great. Whether you search for that function or try to prove the property in another way, trigonalizing the matrix is probably a very good idea (since the matrix multiplication is continuous).